# How to fetch a website as unicode?

Tags: haskell, unicode

I want to fetch a website looking like this¹: naked unicode between tags

```
<html>
한국어
</html>
```

I'm currently using

```
openURL :: String -> IO String
openURL x = getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (getRequest x)
```

But when inspecting the string `한국어` is displayed as `\237\149\156\234\181\173\236\150\180`, 9 characters.
And what I want would be 3 escaped characters like `\u???\u???\u???`

I tried `Text.pack` on `page` where `page <- openURL "url"` but it's already to late then.

¹ If I let firefox show me the source, and page info says UTF-8

Comment: if you want to fetch unicode - it would be best to use [Network.HTTP.Conduit.simpleHttp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.2.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:simpleHttp) and [decodeUtf8](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:decodeUtf8)

Comment: I think almost the same question was asked before. Regardless of that, please always add full informations on dependencies/import to questions that are concerned with some library functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode the text, for example with [`Data.Text.Encoding.decodeUtf8`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#v:decodeUtf8) from `text` or [`Codec.Binary.UTF8.String.decodeString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-1.0.1.1/docs/Codec-Binary-UTF8-String.html#v:decodeString) from `utf8-string`.